# RFC regular expression operators

Tags: regex, rfc, abnf

I recently read an RFC document and I noticed that regex operators that have been used don't match the commonly known. For example:

```
date-time = [ day-of-week "," ] date time [CFWS]
year = (FWS 4*DIGIT FWS) / obs-year
```

The square bracket means that it will match only one out of several characters in it. But in the RFC I see that they interpret it as "optionally". The same with the asterix, that says the preceding token will occur zero times or more. In the example we have

```
4*DIGIT
```

which is not difficult to guess that means 4 occurences of DIGIT token.

How should I interpret the RFC document regex operators, is there any document describing their designation?

Comment: FWIW, I was unsure whether the [regex] tag belonged here given what the answer turned out to be, so it was [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309996/should-i-edit-in-tags-for-the-right-topic).  In case you're not sure what that is, see also [What is "meta"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document (I believe) you're looking at, [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), says this:

> 1.2.2. Syntactic notation
>
> This standard uses the Augmented Backus-Naur Form (ABNF) notation
>      specified in [RFC2234] for the formal definitions of the syntax of
>      messages.

So, yes, the syntax is defined in [RFC 2234](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2234.txt), and is not Regular Expressions.

A few sections specific to the block you've quoted:

> 3.5  Sequence Group
>
> Elements enclosed in parentheses are treated as a single element,
>      whose contents are STRICTLY ORDERED.

> 3.6  Variable Repetition
>
> The operator "*" preceding an element indicates repetition. The full
>      form is:
>
> ```
>    <a>*<b>element
> ```
>
> where <a> and <b> are optional decimal values, indicating at least
>      <a> and at most <b> occurrences of element.

> 3.8  Optional Sequence
>
> Square brackets enclose an optional element sequence:

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't noticed the Syntactic notation section in this document.